# Does the PSU prevent my computer from booting?

Tags: power-supply

My computer just could not power on one day but the power light on MB is on. I have tried resetting CMOS and replacing the battery. I suspect it might be the PSU problem, therefore I tested the PSU powered on by a paperclip with a multimeter. Here is the result.

Yellow : 12.17V
Red : 5.09V
Orange : 3.38V
Blue : -11.6V

Green and grey wire : 2.96V

I think the results of blue and black wire and green and grey wire are abnormal. The former one should be -12V and the later one should be above 5V. Could these two abnormal results prevent my computer from booting?

Answer (score 1):

Your power supply is outputting the correct voltages.  See this chart:

[image]

Black is simply ground and should match the input voltage.
Green is the power on indicator and would be a low a voltage, as would the gray power good wire.

More than likely, something else is causing your computer not to boot.

However, to be 100% sure, you can always use another known working power supply to test on your motherboard.